# What's wrong with these Foolproof Gardenias?

Tags: diagnosis, gardenias

I have 5 foolproof gardenias that are growing in Florida and look very dull and dry with some brown tips on the leaves. I thought they needed water. I've watered more but they are just looking worse and worse. I put some mir acid fertilizer on them with no improvement. Any suggestions are appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Some photos would help.

Comment: What is your location?

Comment: That should have said I put Miracid on them not miracle.  I also sprayed with neem oil.

Comment: I'm sorry- should have said- Zone 9B Florida panhandle very near the coast. Thank you.